Simultaneous overwrite and read causing file not found exception in S3
As part of my requirement we have a raw s3 bucket where initially the data is dumped as binary file and then the file are separately processed and consolidated to json file.
The processor job which runs reads something like below
        spark.read
          .json(sourcePath)
          .coalesce(1)
          .write
          .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
          .json(tempTarget1)

tempTarget1 = (sourcepath + _tmp/)

Once the tempTarget1 path is written with the json file, we delete the sourcepath and then rename the tempTarget1 to sourcepath.
After this we read the sourcepath and process the data and all this is part of same job.
The code functions well and we get the json data perfectly. But recently we have observed that sometimes when processing we are getting filenotFoundException
with messages like:

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

My initial guess is somehow before the whole process of rewriting the files as json and renaming the tempPath spark read picks the older file.But because of lazy reading when the same dataframe goes for processing it throws filenotFoundException.
I have tried thread.sleep(5000) for giving a break before reading, also have tried spark.catalog.clearCache() but all these are not helping.
Still encountering the same issue.
Any pointers or solution from the community is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

What do you mean by rename the tempTarget1 to sourcepath ? Renaming is not possible on s3.

@sarveshseri we are using org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem rename method to rename.

apache s3a and EMR s3 both mock rename() by file by file copy. This is nonatomic and O(data), which is why both use zero-rename committers. you need to switch to these (or full manifest tabular format like iceberg) for safe jobs, then worry about that final write. for that, try to see if you can replicate the problem against a local filesystem to determine whether it is s3 specific
